# How to iterate through IEnumerable collection using for each or foreach?

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable, ienumerator

I want to add one by one values but in for loop how can I iterate
through one by one values and add it inside dictionary.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> items = new Customer[] 
{ 
     new Customer { Name = "test1", Id = 111}, 
     new Customer { Name = "test2", Id = 222} 
};
```

I want to add `{ Name = "test1", Id = 111}` when `i=0`
and want to add `{ Name = "test2", Id = 222}` when `i=1` n so on..

Right now i'm adding full collection in every key.(want to achieve this using foreach or forloop)

```
public async void Set(IEnumerable collection)
{
   RedisDictionary<object,IEnumerable <T>> dictionary = new RedisDictionary>(Settings, typeof(T).Name);
// Add collection to dictionary;
   for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count(); i++)
   { 
     await dictionary.Set(new[] { new KeyValuePair<object,IEnumerable <T>  ( i ,collection) });
   }
}
```

Comment: Not at a computer right now, but I would imagine you could foreach it this way: foreach(KeyValuePair<Settings, typeof(T).Name> item in dictionary)
{
    // Do stuff with item.Key and item.Value
} if not compiler will tell you and call me wrong.

Comment: What is the meaning of parameter "string Key"?

Comment: @knagaev sorry for confusion updated..

Comment: Why is your key an object instead of an in?

Comment: What are you doing with dictionary after all? :)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using async await for adding values to the dictionary? I would have thought the overhead of that is actually more than the relatively simple insertion operation?

Comment: actually  this code is related with redis cache so that is why i need async call

Comment: Why are you receiving an `IEnumerable` to begin with, which doesn't "have" an indexer? It seems like you want to access values by their index?

Comment: Updated question perfectly please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version

```
var dictionary = items.Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue - 1), (o, i) => new { Index = i, Customer = (object)o });
```

By the way, dictionary is a bad name for some variable.

Comment: If I understood what do you want - simple enumeration? Dictionary with an index key and object value from IEnumerable<Customer>?

Answer (score 2):

If the count is need and the IEnumerable is to be maintained, then you can try this:

```
int count = 0;
var enumeratedCollection = collection.GetEnumerator();
while(enumeratedCollection.MoveNext())
{
 count++;
 await dictionary.Set(new[] { new KeyValuePair<object,T>( count,enumeratedCollection.Current) });
}
```

Comment: And where's that `i` in your foreach loop coming from? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm done using

```
string propertyName = "Id";
    Type type = typeof(T);
                var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    await dictionary.Set(new[] { new KeyValuePair<object, T>(prop.GetValue(item, null),item) });
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

So you want to a an item from the collection to the dictionary in the for loop?
If you cast your `IEnumerable` to a list or an array, you can easily access it via the index. For example like this:
Edit: Code at first created a list every time it looped, which should of course be avoided.

```
var list = collection.ToList(); //ToArray() also possible
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
{ 
  dictionary.Add(i, list[i]);
}
```

I'm not 100% if that is what you need, though. More details to your question would be great.

Comment: This is awful. You are creating a list every time you loop

Comment: I don't even know if I got his question right, I just scribbled down a little bit of code to show him how. I will edit it though, because you are of course right and a list shouldn't be created in every iteration.